# min of knight's moves to get to a destination

Tags: java, backtracking, chess

I'm trying to solve this challenge which is to get the min cost of Knight's moves from a source to a destination in a (8*8) chess board and I'm getting a case that not working … I guess I messed up somewhere and I cant figure that out.

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd3RS.jpg)

the full code

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Solution {
    static class Position{
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public Position(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
    
    public static int solution(int src, int dest) {
        int min = 100000000;
        int depth = 0;
        Position source = new Position(0, 0), destination = new Position(0, 0);

        int [][] board = getBoard(src, dest, source, destination);
        
        if(arrived(source, destination)) return 0;
        
        return solve(board, source, destination, (depth), min);
    }
    public static int[][] getBoard(int src, int dest, Position source, Position destination) {
        int c = 0;
        int [][] board = new int[8][8];
         for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
             for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++){
                if(c == src) {
                    board[i][j] = 1;
                    source.x = i;
                    source.y = j;
                }else if(c == dest) {
                    board[i][j] = -1;
                    destination.x = i;
                    destination.y = j;
                }else {
                    board[i][j] = 0;
                }
                 c++;
             }
         }
         return board;
    }
    public static int solve(int[][] board, Position position, Position destination, int depth, int min){
       if(depth > min) {
           return depth;
       }
       
       for(Position p: sort(getPossibleMoves(board, position), destination)){
           if(arrived(p,destination)) {
               return depth + 1;
           }
           board[p.x][p.y] = depth +2;
           int cost = solve(board, p, destination, (depth + 1), min);
           board[p.x][p.y] = 0;
           if(cost < min){
               min = cost;
           }
       }
        return min;
    }
    public static List<Position> sort(List<Position> positions, Position dest) {
        Position temp;
        boolean sorted = false;
        while(!sorted) {
            sorted = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < positions.size() - 1; i++) {
                if(distance(positions.get(i), dest) > distance(positions.get(i+1), dest)) {
                    temp = positions.get(i);
                    positions.set(i, positions.get(i+1));
                    positions.set(i+1, temp);
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return positions;
    }
    public static double distance(Position a, Position b) {
        if(a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y) return 0;
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2));
    }
    public static boolean arrived(Position src, Position dest) {
        return src.x == dest.x && src.y == dest.y;
    }
    public static List<Position> getPossibleMoves(int [][] board, Position current){
        int [][] moves  = {{1,2}, {2,1}, {-1,2}, {1,-2}, {-2,1}, {2,-1}, {-1,-2}, {-2,-1}};
        List<Position> positions = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
            int x = current.x + moves[i][0];
            int y = current.y + moves[i][1];
            if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < board.length && y < board.length && board[x][y] <= 0)
                positions.add(new Position(x, y));
        }
        
        return positions;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(solution(0, 1));

    }
}
```

so here is my approach :
we start from a position and we try all the possible moves (sorted by the nearest) till we find the destination and then do some kind of backtracking to see if there's a better way to get there at a low cost and return the minimum.
some rules I've set :

- the board is represented by a matrix of integers ( full of zeros if empty)
- the source is represented by 1
- the destination is represented by -1
- wherever the knight goes its going to be marked by an integer representing the cost (the start is 1 the second move will be 2 , third 3 and so on …)

let me break the code a little bit down to make it easier

- we start from the function solution `public static int solution(int src, int dest)` which will initialize the board, set the source and destinatin positions, and return the cost using the `solve(board, source, destination, (depth), min)` function
- the function `public static int[][] getBoard(int src, int dest, Position source, Position destination)`  take the board, position … look trough all possible moves ( unmarked positions and sorted by the nearest) for that position and call recursively with a new position until it found the destination or the depth (witch is the cost) is bigger then the minimum that we already have
- the function `public static List<Position> getPossibleMoves(int [][] board, Position current)` will return the 8 possible moves for knight from a position but only those who are not out of the board and are also unvisited ( unvisited will be 0 or -1 for the destination )
- the function `public static List<Position> sort(List<Position> positions, Position dest)` will sort the possible moves by the nearest to the destination ( let's prioritize the nearest one)

please if you can help me figure out what's wrong or if you have another approach I'd really appreciate !

Comment: I think I do not understand what the challenge is about and how that relates to the image you provide. You got a case not working, what is that case exactly? Please add comment to the source. Which part is the setup of the challenge, and which part is your solution?

Comment: thank you for responding ! so this is a google foo.bar challenge and the test that failed is one of the hidden that is why it's so hard see what's wrong

Comment: i only got 2 visible test which they' are : Solution.solution(19, 36)
Output:
    1  and Solution.solution(0, 1)
Output:
    3 all other tests i cant' see the inputs and outputs